# authenticate user using uid of Uniqueid model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to authenticate the user using the "uid". There is a Uniqueid model and has column uid and username. There is a signup form for the user and user needs to put a uid which matches the Uniqueid's uid. 
UserController

```
    def create
    @user= User.new(user_params)
    uid=Uniqueid.find_by(uid: params[:uid])

    if @user.uid === uid
        if @user.save
            session[:user_id]=@user.id
            flash[:success]="Welcome #{@user.username}"

            redirect_to user_path(@user)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

end
```

Uniqueid controller

```
    def create

    @uniqueid=Uniqueid.new(user_params)

    if @uniqueid.save
        flash[:success]="Done"
        redirect_to signup_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end

end
```

Comment: It is definitely good that you want to do something. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: the college has a list of uid in the Unqueid table. When the user is signing up, the college provides the uid and the user needs to put that uid in the signup forrm. If the input of the uid matches the Unquieid's uid then the signup is complete